# SQL Alchemy rollback two transactions

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a python script to process some csv data and put it into a sqlite db which I'm accessing through sqlalchemy.

The calculations are currently implemented in two parts. The second part depends on results of part one already existing in the database. Rewriting the script from scratch do resolve this dependency would be a pain and I'd like to avoid it.

```
def part_one():
    # does stuff
    session.commit()

def part_two():
    # does stuff, including querying part_one's results
    # sometimes this function fails and rollbacks
    session.commit()
```

If `part_two` fails, I want to rollback `part_two` AND `part_one`.
Since `part_two` depends on data existing in the db, I think I'm forced to commit in `part_one`. Otherwise I could just reuse the same session and rollback altogether obviously.

I tried messing about with `session.begin_nested` but didn't get anywhere with that. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I need to either be able to `session.query` against uncommitted changes (that doesn't seem possible) or roll back a previously successfully committed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made this much more complicated than it need to be. What I was looking for was apparently `session.flush` which does all the insert/update/deletes of `part_one` without committing anything.

```
def part_one():
    # does stuff
    session.flush()

def part_two():
    # does stuff, including querying part_one's results
    # sometimes this function fails and rollbacks
    session.commit()
```

Works like a charm